# Android Back/Up arrow not showing after navigation

Tags: java, android

I have a back arrow in my toolbar for an activity.
It shows up correctly when I land on the activity. But after I go back and come again to the same activity, it is not showing. **This activity is in a library that I am creating **. 
So when we import this library into another project and call this activity from the main project activity then this problem occurs. The code runs, but from consecutive activity calls, the arrow is not visible. I have to relaunch the whole app to see the arrow.

Activity Code

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_A);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ...
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);// code runs but arrow is not showing
        }
}

@Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }

@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        this.finish();
        Log.d(TAG, "onBackPressed: Finished!!");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this its working on my code.

```
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: No this didn't helped... for first time title is not visible. And consecutive loading, title comes back but arrow is still not visible.

Answer (score 0):

```
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: @DanielCottone what link? There's no links in here

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to update you manifest file setting up the parent activity name.

```
  <activity
        android:name=".WebActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        />
```